# Clearing a text entry field after processing the input

Tags: angularjs

Having completed CodeSchool's AngularJS course, I'm trying to go back through and use what I've learned to build a simple to-do app. I've gotten it to the point where I can add entries to a list, but I'm not able to clear the text entry field after I've used the input. Here's my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jharris/0duxpme4/1/).

Specifically, here's my `addComment()` function:

```
card.addComment = function(newComment) {
  card.comments.push(newComment.text);
  newComment = {text: ""};
};
```

And the corresponding Angular HTML:

```
<form ng-submit="card.addComment(newComment)">
    <input name="comment" placeholder="Add comment" ng-model="newComment.text">
</form>
```

At first I was passing the data in as a string (`<input ng-model="newComment">` instead of `newComment.text`), but then I remembered that strings get passed by value, not by reference. I figured `newComment` was being blanked in the function but not passed back through Angular to the document. But even after I changed `newComment` to an object so it would be passed by reference, it made no difference--clearing the value in JavaScript has no effect on the page. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
card.addComment = function(newComment) {
  card.comments.push(newComment.text);
  newComment.text = "";
};
```

What you're doing is creating a new object on the scope and breaking the binding which was set up on the original object. By updating the `text` property only, you leave the binding intact and achieve your goal of clearing the input field to which it is bound.

Comment: This problem occured OP has not followed the rule of prototypal inheritance properly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs Declaring object again will create a new object for that property..prototypal inheritance gets failed in that case

Comment: better you add that in your answer..I tried to edit your answer couple of time...but in between you were editing it..

Comment: @PankajParkar This question has nothing to do with prototypal inheritance and scopes, it has to do with pass-by-object-reference semantics in JavaScript.

Comment: I spend so long chasing this issue, I can't believe the solution was so simple. Thank you for the simple and clear explanation.

Comment: @AlexisKing I've bad understanding regarding it..Thanks for showing me right way. :)

Answer (score 2):

> I remembered that strings get passed by value, not by reference.

This line of reasoning is incorrect. Everything in JavaScript gets passed by *object reference*. See this question: [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

Replacing the raw string with an object *does* potentially buy you some affordance, though. However, whether or not it's a string or an object (and indeed, a string *is* an object!), `newComment = someValue` will never work.

Instead, you'll need to set the `text` *property* on the object. This doesn't create a new object, it just modifies a property, so the reference is preserved. Try this instead:

```
newComment.text = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rest a form which may do what you require

```
document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
```